# datetime manipulation through pandas groupby

Tags: pandas, datetime

Strating from the dataset below :

| User_id | temp_Id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 01/02/2020 |
| A | A1 | 01/02/2020 |
| A | A2 | 05/02/2020 |
| A | A3 | 07/02/2020 |
| B | B1 | 01/01/2020 |
| C | C1 | 05/01/2020 |
| C | C2 | 06/02/2020 |
| D | D1 | 07/01/2020 |
| D | D2 | 08/02/2020 |
| D | D3 | 09/02/2020 |

how would I get a new dataframe with two columns such that for each `user_id` (1st columns) the second column will provide the difference between the last and previous connection date ?
PS: for B the results will be zero

It worked using nested loop over all user_id but I am looking for the most pythonic way to do that. I guess pandas.groupby would be the best thing to do.

Thank you

Edit:Date time format is Day/Month/Year

The desired output would be like this

| User_id | Delta |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 31 |
| D | 1 |

Comment: What would be your expected outcome for this df?

Comment: is date a month/year?

Comment: day/month the results should be given in days

Comment: a year helps in calculating the days, which year is assumed otherwise?

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question with the desired output

Comment: how is Delta calculated, can you add some more details on calculations

Comment: how you arrived at 2 for user-id 'A'?

Comment: for 'A', it is 07-05 since

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the year is 2020
if your date has a year as part of it, then the first line in computing date2, is to be modified

calculate a date as yyyy-mm-dd in a new column in the df

using groupby and transform to calculate the difference between current and previous as days

updated line one, now that the date has a year as part of it

```
###df['date2'] = df['Date'].str.split('/').apply(lambda x: '2020-'+x[1]+'-'+x[0] ).astype('datetime64')

# date is in dd/mm/yyyy format
df['date2'] = df['Date'].str.split('/').apply(lambda x: x[2]+'-'+x[1]+'-'+x[0] ).astype('datetime64')

df['diff']=df.groupby('User_id')['date2'].transform(lambda y: y-y.shift(1))
```

```
    User_id temp_Id Date    date2       diff
0   A         A1    01/02   2020-02-01  NaT
1   A         A1    01/02   2020-02-01  0 days
2   A         A2    05/02   2020-02-05  4 days
3   A         A3    07/02   2020-02-07  2 days
4   B         B1    01/01   2020-01-01  NaT
5   C         C1    05/01   2020-01-05  NaT
6   C         C2    06/02   2020-02-06  32 days
7   D         D1    07/01   2020-01-07  NaT
8   D         D2    08/02   2020-02-08  32 days
9   D         D3    09/02   2020-02-09  1 days
```

obtaining the last value, after question is updated with more details

```
df.groupby(['User_id'])['diff'].last().to_frame()
```

```
User_id diff
A       2 days
B       NaT
C       32 days
D       1 days
```

Comment: The result should be a new dataframe as in my edited question. A new dataframe with two columns and as many rows as unique user_id

Comment: can you format the desired output?

Comment: the last value from the group is chosen. I hope the solution addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

the second column will provide the difference between the last and previous connection date.

Can you give me the sample desired output?

I added the answer

```
def get_result(list_day):
    list_day = sorted(list_day)
    if list_day == 1:
        return 0
    return (list_day[-1] - list_day[-2]).days

group_df = df.groupby("User_id")["Date"].apply(lambda x: get_result(list(x)))
group_df
```